# How to extract documentation from Django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models, documentation

I have a project written as a django app. Although it is in the middle of frequent changes, but the client insists on having the latest database model changes in my project. I had to create a libreoffice document and keep it updated with the latest table/column changes in my django `models.py` file. It has started to get annoying.

So I'm curious is there already a tool or django app available to extract information from model metadata (class document, `help_text`, `Field` classes, relations, etc) from django models and create a nice document (TXT/TeX/ODF/PDF etc) out of it? django can already produce SQL commands, so I think it should be possible.

Any suggestions?

The document in my mind could contain paragraphs for describing each DB table (from model class docstring), and a bullet list of field names and their descriptions and possible DB attributes (being indexed, unique, column type) in front of them.

Comment: What information do you want to record?

Comment: Have you tried [Sphinx](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-documentation/#getting-started-with-sphinx) ? It has decent features right from the box.

Comment: I had similar problems before. We have 2 teams work on the same project in different countries so each team need to know db changes made by the other team. We finally decided to use django-extensions to create some model graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pydoc`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html) can give you basic documentation from the docstrings used, but for a fuller set of documentation you'll want to use [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/), which is used to create both the Python and Django documentation web pages and downloads.